# Publishing image service with JSON in ArcGIS Server creates inaccessible service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-rest-api, image-service

I used the following JSON to publish but it created inaccessible layer that I could not modify or delete.

```
{ 
   "serviceName":"Suitability_1574658353.68_proj",
   "type":"ImageServer",
   "description":"User uploaded image.",
   "capabilities":"Image,Metadata,Mensuration",
   "outputType":"imageService",
   "configuredState":"STARTED",
   "maxWaitTime":6000,
   "maxStartupTime":300,
   "maxIdleTime":1800,
   "maxUsageTime":600000,
   "outputDir":"C:/arcgisserver/directories/arcgisoutput",
   "supportedImageReturnTypes":"URL",
   "virtualOutputDir":"/rest/directories/arcgisoutput",
   "properties":{ 
      "defaultCompressionTolerance":"0.01",
      "maxBufferCount":"100",
      "maxImageHeight":"2048",
      "path":"D:/data/User/1574658353.68/Suitability_1574658353.68_proj.tif",
      "supportsOwnershipBasedAccessControl":"false",
      "description":"User uploaded file.",
      "defaultCompressionQuality":"75",
      "esriImageServiceSourceType":"esriImageServiceSourceTypeDataset",
      "hasValidSR":"true",
      "isCached":"false",
      "virtualOutputDir":"/rest/directories/arcgisoutput",
      "availableMensurationCapabilities":"Basic",
      "dataSourceIsReadOnly":"true",
      "exportTilesAllowed":"false",
      "cacheOnDemand":"false",
      "maxSampleCount":"1000",
      "defaultResamplingMethod":"1",
      "minScale":"-1",
      "useLocalCacheDir":"true",
      "maxScale":"-1",
      "allowFunction":"true",
      "availableCompressions":"None,JPEG,LZ77,LERC",
      "supportedImageReturnTypes":"URL",
      "clientCachingAllowed":"true",
      "allowedMensurationCapabilities":"Basic",
      "maxExportTilesCount":"100000",
      "returnJPGPNGAsJPG":"false",
      "ignoreCache":"false",
      "colormapToRGB":"false",
      "cacheControlMaxAge":"43200",
      "allowedTemplates":"None",
      "virtualCacheDir":"/rest/directories/arcgiscache",
      "allowedCompressions":"None,JPEG,LZ77,LERC",
      "availableMosaicMethods":""
   }
}
```

The service is accessible in the client side but I cannot delete it in arcgis/admin or server manager. 
When I open the published service in ArcGIS Server Manager, I get a blank page. When I open the service in arcgis/admin, I get the following error message:

```
 Error
     Could not find resource or operation 
    'Suitability_1574658353.68_proj.ImageServer' on the system.
 Code
    404
```

Am I missing something in my JSON?

I am working on ArcGIS 10.5 Server.

Comment: Try replacing the "53.68" with "53_68"

Comment: It worked! Thanks! The dot was the issue! Could post an answer?